# Counting inversions - char array doesn't want to swap?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to count inversions in permutation and in order to do this I have to make a swap. The point is A char array must look like B, and I'm trying to use something like bubblesort mechanism, but swap doesn't work at all and I don't know why, here is a code:

```
char[] john = {'A', 'A', 'C', 'B'};
    char[] marg = {'B', 'A', 'C', 'A'};

    for(int i=0; i<john.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<john.length; j++){                 
                if(marg[i]==john[j]){
                    char temp = john[j];
                    john[j] = john[j-1];
                    john[j-1] = temp;
                    counter++;
                }                                       
        }
    }
```

After that loop john array looks exactly the same like before.

I want to transform char array john into marg (with counting all swaps), so for this example counter should have value 4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Attach a debugger and debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should swap `john[j]` with `john[i]`, not `john[j]` with `john[j-1]`. Currently you do swap the last two elements of john two times and thus get the input as result.